# Can I declare war without involving my allies?

Tags: stellaris

I'm in an alliance with two other empires, and I want to declare war on another empire which currently has one planet.

The target empire only has one planet, which I want to take for myself but my allies keep voting no when I propose war. Is there a way I can declare war without needing the apporval of my allies and without leaving the alliance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, an alliance goes to war entirely or not at all. You could demand vassalization from a one-planet empire though.